# Debugging application wirelessly takes more time compare to debug using wire

Tags: iphone, ios11

Are there any settings I am missing or it is just like that only?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do it right. There are no options for wireless build configuration. Breakpoints work very slow as well. Maybe this issue will fix fixes in next betas or GM or release version, but... I'm not sure ‍♂️